# Simple grammar looping infinitely

Tags: antlr4

I would expect this simple grammar to match strings such as 'abc':

```
grammar Hello;

entry
  :  LETTER+
  ;

LETTER : [a-z] ;
```

But it seems to enter an infinite loop:

```
C:\Code\antlr\hello>antlr4 Hello.g4 -encoding utf8

C:\Code\antlr\hello>javac Hello*.java

C:\Code\antlr\hello>grun Hello entry -tree
asdf^Z

Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

Why?

Comment: What are you doing that you think should make it stop?

Comment: @ScottHunter Shouldn't it stop automatically when it runs out of input?

Comment: Instead of typing the input in, try `type in.txt | java -cp "c:\Downloads\antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar;." org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig Hello entry -tree`, where `in.txt` contains the input, and you pass the correct path to the .jar file. "Why?" The EOF character IS NOT a character but a condition that terminates and closes the input stream. That occurs on Windows with Java on a new line followed immediately with a control-z when attached to a terminal. Bypass all this BS and just "cat" the input directly as is to your program.

Comment: @kaby76 That did it, thanks!